# Do i need to setup a server to use spotifys authorization code flow?

Tags: node.js, express, spotify, electron

I am using Electron to create an app for my raspberry pi to run and i want to be able to use my spotify playlists but i am having a little trouble using their api. I need to use their authorization code flow which grants you an access token after you login in. My question is, do i need to have my app running on a server (in localhost) in order to be able to make use of the spotify api ? I started playing around with Express but i am still not quite sure what i am doing or need to do.

Has anyone done this before or have any advice?

Are there any nodejs modules that help with this kind of authentication?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092808/is-it-possible-to-use-the-spotify-web-api-to-write-a-desktop-application-without) is a nice explanation